# Regular expression REGEXP_LIKE

Tags: sql, oracle

Please help me with my regular expression:

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(dbField, '*п* 2($| )', 'i')
```

But I find:

```
"кран № 2 пом. 144"
"кр. № 2 пом. 260"
...
```

I don't understand why I find that. It must be "п" before "2". What's wrong? (db oracle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

regexp `п*` means `symbol "п", repeated 0 or more times`
Try

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(dbField, 'п.*2($| )', 'i')
```

or simply and faster

```
WHERE lower(dbField)||' ' LIKE '%п%2 %'
```

Comment: I fix my query:REGEXP_LIKE(dbField, '.*п+.* 144($| ).*к+.* 2$', 'i')

Comment: You can skip `.*` at the start of regexp

Comment: `REGEXP_LIKE(dbField, 'п.* 144($| .*к.* 2$)', 'i')`